# Easy way to assign int pointer values?

Tags: go

Given a `struct` that looks like

```
type foo struct {
 i *int
}
```

if I want to set `i` to 1, I must

```
throwAway := 1
instance := foo { i: &throwAway }
```

Is there any way to do this in a single line without having to give my new `i` value it's own name (in this case `throwaway`)?

Comment: I recommend to check [this extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go/30716481#answer-30716481) to a very similar question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed in the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/YcfJzrj0Lec/4LHLVpt-xSAJ), you can just do this:

```
func intPtr(i int) *int {
    return &i
}
```

and then

```
instance := foo { i: intPtr(1) }
```

if you have to do it often. `intPtr` gets inlined (see `go build -gcflags '-m'` output), so it should have next to no performance penalty.

Comment: You can also do `instance := foo{ i: new(int) }; foo.i = 1;` if you don't want to write a separate function.

Comment: That's not right @FUZxxl, you can't assign `1` as a type `int` to `*int`. You end up back in the same situation as the OP.

Comment: Sorry, try `instance := foo{i : new(int) }; *foo.i = 1;`

Comment: @fuz I get this: `type ‘foo’ has no method ‘i’`

Comment: @exebook Please ask a new question for that if you can't solve it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

No this is not possible to do in one line.

Comment: Gross.  Any thoughts as to why not?  Is it just too difficult to implement to remove an occasionally noisy line?

Comment: @MushinNoShin: a pointer is the address of some thing, so you need that *thing*.

Comment: @maerics: that was already understood, this was asking if there's any convenient ways to automatically do the memory allocation in the background and keep the unnecessary noise out of my code.  See the accepted answer.

Comment: Pointers to ints are not that common and pointers to literal ints are very uncommon, so why bother with syntactical sugar?

Comment: @Volker you should take a look at `aws-sdk-golang`, they've got pointers to literal ints for days.