# How do I represent an Optional String in Go?

Tags: string, go, null, option-type, variant

I wish to model a value which can have two possible forms: absent, or a string.

The natural way to do this is with `Maybe String`, or `Optional<String>`, or `string option`, etc. However, Go does not have variant types like this.

I then thought, following Java, C, etc., that the alternative would be nullability, or `nil` in Go. However, `nil` is not a member of the `string` type in Go.

Searching, I then thought to use the type `*string`. This could work, but seems very awkward (e.g. I cannot take the address of the string literal in the same way that I can take the address of a struct literal).

What is the idiomatic way to model such a value in Go?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30716481/1705598. It is for `*int64`, but you can use the same solutions for `*string`.

Comment: In your application is there a semantic difference between a string that is unset (absent) and ""? Most of the time, in my experience, you can effectively treat them the same.  The empty string `""` is the zero value for a string in go. This is idiomatic but maybe you need this distinction?

Comment: @SkyeC the problem with that is that it does not express optionality in the types; it's just an unreliable convention.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use something like [`sql.NullString`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString), but I personally would stick to `*string`. As for awkwardness, it's true that you can't just `sp := &"foo"` unfortunately. But there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29520834/1892060) for this:

```
func strPtr(s string) *string {
    return &s
}
```

Calls to `strPtr("foo")` should be inlined, so it's effectively `&"foo"`.

Another possibility is to use `new`:

```
sp := new(string)
*sp = "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks. It does seem like the pointer solution is as good as I'll get, which is disappointing. Why oh why in the 21st century do languages still not have variant types/sum types/ADTs.

Comment: The type `Optional<String>` adds value in languages which use exceptions for error handling. Golang makes error handling explicit via return values, however.

Comment: @MichalČizmazia languages such as Haskell use `Maybe` (which is `Optional` by another name) and do not, under normal circumstances, use exceptions for error handling. In fact, `Optional` types have nothing to do with exceptions and are a compile-time check (as opposed to exceptions).

Comment: @AndresF. you are right! Functional programming takes `Optional` far beyond the `getOrThrow` operation I was referring to.

Comment: @jameshfisher I recommend use  sql.NullString,string pointer can be aweful thing that you need check nill and deference it everywhere,and may cause unexpected nil crash.

Answer (score 17):

A logical solution would be to use `*string` as mentioned by Ainar-G. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go/30716481#30716481) details the possibilities of obtaining a pointer to a value (`int64` but the same works for `string` too). A wrapper is another solution.

#### Using just `string`

An optional `string` means a `string` plus 1 specific value (or state) saying "not a string" (but a `null`).

This 1 specific value can be stored (signaled) in another variable (e.g `bool`) and you can pack the `string` and the `bool` into a `struct` and we arrived to the wrapper, but this doesn't fit into the case of "using just a `string`" (but is still a viable solution).

If we want to stick to just a `string`, we can take out 1 specific value from the possible values of a `string` type (which has "infinity" possible values as the length is not limited (or maybe it is as it must be an `int` but that's all right)), and we can name this specific value the `null` value, the value which means "not a string".

The most convenient value for indicating `null` is the zero value of `string`, which is the empty `string`: `""`. Designating this the `null` element has the convenience that whenever you create a `string` variable without explicitly specifying the initial value, it will be initialized with `""`. Also when querying an element from a `map` whose value is `string` will also yield `""` if the key is not in the `map`.

This solution suits many real-life use-cases. If the optional `string` is supposed to be a person's name for example, an empty `string` does not really mean a valid person name, so you shouldn't allow that in the first place.

There might be cases of course when the empty `string` does represent a valid value of a variable of `string` type. For these use-cases we can choose another value.

In Go, a `string` is in effect a read-only slice of bytes. See blog post [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](http://blog.golang.org/strings) which explains this in details.

So a `string` is a byte slice, which is the UTF-8 encoded bytes in case of a valid text. Assuming you want to store a valid text in your optional `string` (if you wouldn't, then you can just use a `[]byte` instead which can have a `nil` value), you can choose a `string` value which represents an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence and thus you won't even have to make a compromise to exclude a valid text from the possible values. The shortest invalid UTF-8 byte sequence is 1 byte only, for example `0xff` (there are more). Note: you can use the [`utf8.ValidString()`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#ValidString) function to tell if a `string` value is a valid text (valid UTF-8 encoded byte sequence).

You can make this exceptional value a `const`:

```
const Null = "\xff"
```

Being this short also means it will be very fast to check if a `string` equals to this.
And by this convention you already have an optional `string` which also allows the empty `string`.

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dL9D3twKkD).

```
const Null = "\xff"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(utf8.ValidString(Null)) // false

    s := Null
    fmt.Println([]byte(s)) // [255]
    fmt.Println(s == Null) // true
    s = "notnull"
    fmt.Println(s == Null) // false
}
```

Comment: However, using this method, we might lose the context that s might be null.

Answer (score 2):

With an interface type, you can use a more natural assignment syntax.

```
var myString interface{} // used as type <string>
myString = nil // nil is the default -- and indicates 'empty'
myString = "a value"
```

When referencing the value, a [type assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38816843/86967) is typically required to make the checking explicit.

```
// checked type assertion
if s, exists := myString.(string); exists {
    useString(s)
}
```

Also, because of [stringers](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17) there are some contexts in which the 'optional' type will be handled automatically -- meaning that you don't need to explicitly cast the value.  The `fmt` package uses this feature:

```
fmt.Println("myString:",myString) // prints the value (or "<nil>")
```

---

### Warning

**There is no type-checking when assigning to the value.**

In some ways, this is a cleaner approach than dealing with pointers.  However, because this uses an interface type, it is not limited to holding a specific underlying type.  The risk is that you could unintentionally assign a different type -- which would be treated the same as `nil` in the above conditional.

Here's a demonstration of assignment using interfaces:

```
var a interface{} = "hello"
var b = a // b is an interface too
b = 123 // assign a different type

fmt.Printf("a: (%T) %v\n", a, a)
fmt.Printf("b: (%T) %v\n", b, b)
```

Output:

```
a: (string) hello
b: (int) 123
```

*Notice that interfaces are assigned by duplication, so `a` and `b` are distinct.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface, which is idiomatic Go:

```
type (
    // An interface which represents an optional string.
    StrOpt interface{ implStrOpt() }

    StrOptVal  string   // A string value for StrOpt interface.
    StrOptNone struct{} // No value for StrOpt interface.
)

func (StrOptVal) implStrOpt()  {} // implement the interface
func (StrOptNone) implStrOpt() {}
```

And this is how you use it:

```
func Foo(maybeName StrOpt) {
    switch val := maybeName.(type) {
    case StrOptVal:
        fmt.Printf("String value! -> %s\n", string(val))
    case StrOptNone:
        fmt.Println("No value!")
    default:
        panic("StrOpt does not accept a nil value.")
    }
}

func main() {
    Foo(StrOptVal("hello world"))
    Foo(StrOptNone{})
}
```

Test it in the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RJo_tDCqZVQ).

Answer (score 0):

There is a cataloged open source solution, for primitive types, inspired by 'Java [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)'.

Official documentation for `package optional` is here:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/markphelps/optional

The motivation given is:

> In Go, variables declared without an explicit initial value are given their zero value. Most of the time this is what you want, but sometimes you want to be able to tell if a variable was set or if it's just a zero value. That's where option types come in handy.

For `optional.String`, as an example, it has the following interface:

```
type String
func NewString(v string) String
func (s String) Get() (string, error)
func (s String) If(fn func(string))
func (s String) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
func (s String) MustGet() string
func (s String) OrElse(v string) string
func (s String) Present() bool
func (s *String) Set(v string)
func (s *String) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error
```

---

The latest GitHub verified (signed) release is [v0.10.0](https://github.com/markphelps/optional/releases/tag/v0.10.0) on Jun 4, 2022.

```
go get -u github.com/markphelps/optional/cmd/optional@v0.10.0
```

---

A subtlety in the documentation: To undefine a value, assign `{}` or `optional.String{}`.

Comment: "It can also be used as a tool to generate option type wrappers around your own types."