# Difference between *string and sql.NullString

Tags: go

I've been strugguling with SQL NULL values in Golang recently. After trying to unsuccessfully unmarshal JSON objects using `Decode()` and `sql.NullString`, I came to this answer on StackOverflow :

[Assigning null to JSON fields instead of empty strings in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048557/assigning-null-to-json-fields-instead-of-empty-strings-in-golang#answer-31048860)

The solution using a string pointer seems to work perfectly with Decode() and nil values. So what is the difference between `sql.NullString` and `*string` ?
Is it just about nil checking ?

Comment: A NULL coming from sql is not the same that a Go nil. Take a look to [NullString](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

SQL has different null values than Golang.

If you look at the definition of `sql.NullString` then this is what you get:

```
type NullString struct {
    String string
    Valid  bool // Valid is true if String is not NULL
}
```

As you can see, `sql.NullString` is a way to represent null string coming from SQL (which correspond to "NULL").
On the other hand, a nil `*string` is a pointer to a string which is nil, so the two are different.

Comment: That's pretty smart and clean

Comment: Is thr any advantage using `sql.NullString` over using `*string`?

Comment: [From Russ Cox](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/vOTFu2SMNeA/m/GB5v3JPSsicJ):


`There's no effective difference. We thought people might want to use NullString because it is so common and perhaps expresses the intent more clearly than *string. But either will work.`

Comment: thanks @sepehr that quotes makes sense. The answer is misleading. Strictly speaking a null is not a nil, but at a higher level they both represent the very same concept.

Comment: `nil` has no type, `sql.NullString` does, so it's better to use `sql.NullString`, but people don't want to do the extra typing so they just defaulted to `*string`, which IMHO is an ugly hack.

Comment: How would you convert `*string` to `sql.NullString`? What I can think of is uglier than the "hack".

Comment: @TimoHuovinen What you said "uglier hack" might not be uglier. Using pointer is not database specific. And the result can be marshaled into JSON directly.

Answer (score 0):

Making @sepehr's comment in the previous answer an answer of it's own, and adding some conversion functions I find helpful.

From [Russ Cox](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/vOTFu2SMNeA/m/GB5v3JPSsicJ)

> There's no effective difference. We thought people might want to use NullString because it is so common and perhaps expresses the intent more clearly than *string. But either will work

In fact, a few generic functions make it easy to convert from `*string` and `sql.NullString` with a minimum of fuss:

```golang
func DerefOrEmpty[T any](val *T) T {
    if val == nil {
        var empty T
        return empty
    }
    return *val
}

func IsNotNil[T any](val *T) bool {
    return val != nil
}
```

Usage:

```golang
func main() {
    var comment string = "hello"
    commentPtr := &comment

    sqlStrComment := sql.NullString{
        String: DerefOrEmpty(commentPtr),
        Valid:  IsNotNil(commentPtr),
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", sqlStrComment)

    commentPtr = nil
    sqlStrComment = sql.NullString{
        String: DerefOrEmpty(commentPtr),
        Valid:  IsNotNil(commentPtr),
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", sqlStrComment)
}
```

Playground link at https://go.dev/play/p/KFNHe2iJmGU