# Unmarshalling a sql.NullTime struct in Go

Tags: sql, go, null-string

Given

```
type NullTime struct {
    Time  time.Time
    Valid bool // Valid is true if Time is not NULL
}
```

and

```
type PayinCount struct {
    DateShiftStart sql.NullTime    `json:"dateShiftStart"`
    DateShiftEnd   sql.NullTime    `json:"dateShiftend"`
}
```

when I  process the following JSON

```
{
    "dateShiftStart":"2023-10-16",
    "dateShiftEnd":"2023-10-23"
}
```

with

```
var payinsCount PayinsCount
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &payinsCount)
if err != nil {
    sendErrorResponse(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
```

where sendErrorResponse is the following helper process

```
func sendErrorResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, err string, statusCode int) {
    messageStatusCode := MessageStatusCode{
        Message:    err,
        StatusCode: statusCode}
    w.WriteHeader(statusCode)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(messageStatusCode)
}
```

I get the following message

```
{
    "message": "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field PayinsCount.dateShiftStart of type sql.NullTime",
    "statusCode": 400
}
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You cannot "resolve" this error. You have to make PayinCount implement encoding/json.Unmarshaler if you want to keep sql.NullTime

Comment: The function: sendErrorResponse where does that come from I took your code snippits and none of the pkgs seem to recognise that function

Comment: Send error response is a helper routine. Discovered it's not so easy to write  encoding/json Unmarshaller for sql.NullTime. PayinsCount is just an example of types using a sql.NullType.

Comment: I remembered I had something like this a long time ago. The answers are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961358/how-do-you-marshal-a-sql-nullstring-such-that-the-output-is-flattened-to-give-ju

Comment: A little different from that old question. This solution needs to handle 'yyyy-mm-dd' and 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' strings.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison (1) unmarshal into a string, (2) use regexp to check if its date or date-time to determine the layout, (3) parse the string with the layout.

Comment: What output are you wanting?

Comment: @Jason - A payinsCount instance of type PayinsCount

Comment: Good thinking @mkopriva - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following.
I added the following type.

```
type NullDate sql.NullTime
```

then I changed PayinsCount to use NullDate

```
type PayinsCount struct {
    DateShiftStart NullDate      `json:"dateShiftStart,omitempty"`
    DateShiftEnd   NullDate      `json:"dateShiftend,omitempty"`
}
```

then I created

```
// UnmarshalJSON for NullDate
func (nd *NullDate) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    s := string(b)
    s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, "\"", "")

    x, err := time.Parse(time.DateOnly, s)
    if err != nil {
        nd.Valid = false
        return err
    }

    nd.Time = x
    nd.Valid = true
    return nil
}
```

now when I process the following JSON

```
{
    "dateShiftStart":"2023-10-16",
    "dateShiftEnd":"2023-10-23"
}
```

with

```
var payinsCount PayinsCount
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &payinsCount)
if err != nil {
    sendErrorResponse(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
```

it works. I end up with a valid PayinsCount instance.

For completeness here is the MarshalJSON function for NullDate

```
// MarshalJSON for NullDate
func (nd NullDate) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !nd.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    val := fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", nd.Time.Format(time.DateOnly))
    return []byte(val), nil
}
```

Note the escaped double quotes - without them the encoding/json marshalling code was processing the date string in 3 chunks and I was getting the following error

```
error(*encoding/json.SyntaxError) *{msg: "invalid character '-' after top-level value", Offset: 0}
```