# In Golang trying to deserialize to struct in golang

Tags: go, struct, google-app-engine-golang

Actually Iam trying to fetch the data from the sql server (particular table), my expectation is to deserialize the data fetched from the sql server to **struct** in GoLang.

Declared the struct below

```
type TrnVmSeries struct {
    VmCode   sql.NullString
    IsHidden sql.NullBool
    Cores    sql.NullInt32
    Ram      sql.NullFloat64
}
```

```
func ReadSqlData() {
    var con *sql.DB = SqlConnection()
    defer CloseConnection(con)

    var resObj []model.TrnVmSeries

    rows, err := con.Query("select * from testGo")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error executing query:", err.Error())
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        var vm model.TrnVmSeries
        if err := rows.Scan(&vm.VmCode, &vm.IsHidden, &vm.Cores, &vm.Ram); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        resObj = append(resObj, vm)
    }

    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(resObj)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Json serialized Data %v", string(jsonData))
    fmt.Println("Object Output", resObj[0])
}
```

I have tried this getting below output

`[
{
"VmCode": {
"String":"",
"Valid":false
},
"IsHidden":{
"Bool":false,
"Valid":true
},
"Cores":{
"Int32":0,
"Valid":true
},
"Ram":
{
"Float64":10,
"Valid":true
}

}
]`

But whats **my expectation** is below

`[ { "VmCode": null, "IsHidden": false "Cores": 0 "Ram": 10 } ]`

I don't know how to achieve this some one please help me on this. To get expected object. Also attached SQL table stucture

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `sql.Null*` - you can just use pointers:

```
type TrnVmSeries struct {
    VmCode   *string
    IsHidden *bool
    Cores    *int32
    Ram      *float64
}
```

Or you can have your own custom Null types that implement json marshaling the way you want, e.g.

```
type NullString sql.NullString
type NullBool sql.NullBool
type NullInt32 sql.NullInt32
type NullFloat64 sql.NullFloat64

func (s NullString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if s.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(s.String)
    }
    return []byte(`null`), nil
}

// same thing for the other Null types...

type TrnVmSeries struct {
    VmCode   NullString
    IsHidden NullBool
    Cores    NullInt32
    Ram      NullFloat64
}
```

Per your comment, you also need to be able to print the object, in which case you just need to implement the [Stringer](https://go.dev/tour/methods/17) interface, e.g. https://go.dev/play/p/AkV0_SvK6fi

Comment: I think dave's answer is good enough but this post can help you understand `*string` and `NullString`.
In short, there is no concrete difference and you might prefer `*string` in the case of Json serialization.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092155/difference-between-string-and-sql-nullstring

Comment: But I required actual value in a struct. After making the properties to *string, when i try to print the object it shows like `[{<nil> 0xc00000a052 0xc00000a058 0xc00000a060}]`

while serialization I have got the expected `[{"VmCode":null,"IsHidden":true,"Cores":1,"Ram":101}]` I required the same in struct as well

Comment: Or In need to **assign the actual same value to another struct** is required
@dave