# How to unmarshal emtpy string as nil

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

If I have some JSON data like this:

```
{
  nullableID: ""
}
```

How can I get unmarshalling this struct:

```
help := struct {
  ID *primitive.ObjectID `json:"nullableID",omitempty`
}{}
```

To decode into `help` such that `help.ID == nil`

Comment: If that's what you really want to do, set the `UnmarshalJSON` method on `primitive.ObjectID` to do that. But this smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the actual problem to be solved?

Comment: And note that your struct tag is invalid. It should be `json:"nullableID,omitempty"`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/31048557/13860

Comment: It's more an "is there an easy way to do this" type of question. I understand I can parse the request object as a string and then make a new struct while converting those string to `primitive.ObjectID`s its just a bunch of lines and tons of `if err != nil`s that I would like to avoid

Comment: A custom unmarshaler should be maybe 3 lines, or 5 max.

Comment: But more important: why? Are you sure this is even needed?

Comment: No, a custom unmarshaller is not needed since this is a one-off which is only because old mobile clients are sending an empty string instead of null. I wanted to know if there was some tag like "omitempty" that could do what I wanted with a few characters.

Comment: No, there's no tag to do this. A custom unmarshaler is the idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have `ObjectID` implement the `Unmarshaler` interface and check for an empty string:

```
func (o *ObjectID) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  if err := json.Unmarshal(data, o); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  if string(*o) == "" {
    o = nil
  }
  return nil
}
```

If the `ObjectID` type is imported from another package, you can create a new type that wraps that type:

```
// objID is a copy of primitive.ObjectID but with it's own json unmarshalling.
type objID struct {
  *primitive.ObjectID
}

func (o *objID) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  // Same implementation as above
}
```

[This article](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/advanced-encoding-decoding/) explains it in a lot more detail.

Comment: That code won't even compile. `o == ""` is invalid.

Comment: @Flimzy I’m not sure what the type of ObjectId is, you’ll probably have to cast it to a string before you compare it. ‘if string(o) == “”’

Comment: I'm not sure what type `ObjectId` is either, except that it's a pointer, and a pointer will never `== ""`. `string(o) == ""` will also never work on a pointer.

Comment: You're right, I didn't try to run the code. I added a cast and a de-reference. That code won't be right for every type, but I tried to keep it short and simple for the simplest case here.