# Explain Type Assertions in Go

Tags: go

I'm reading about type assertions `x.(T)` in [The Go Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134190440) and don't understand them.

I understand that there are different scenarios:

- T is a concrete type or an interface
- One (asserted value?) or two (ok) values can be returned

This is what I don't understand:

- Why would I use them?
- What exactly do they return?

I have also googled on the topic and still don't understand.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

## Short answer

In one line:

> `x.(T)` asserts that `x` is not nil and that the value stored in `x` is of type `T`.

#### Why would I use them:

- to check `x` is nil
- to check what is the dynamic type held by interface `x`
- to extract the dynamic type from `x`

#### What exactly they return:

- `t := x.(T)` => t is of type `T`; if `x` is nil, it panics.
- `t,ok := x.(T)` => if `x` is nil or not of type `T` => `ok` is `false` otherwise `ok` is `true` and `t` is of type `T`.

---

## Detailed explanation

Imagine you need to calculate area of 4 different shapes: Circle, Square, Rectangle and Triangle. You may define new types with a new method called `Area()`, like this:

```golang
type Circle struct {
    Radius float64
}
func (t Circle) Area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * t.Radius * t.Radius
}
```

And for `Triangle` :

```golang
type Triangle struct {
    A, B, C float64 // lengths of the sides of a triangle.
}
func (t Triangle) Area() float64 {
    p := (t.A + t.B + t.C) / 2.0 // perimeter half
    return math.Sqrt(p * (p - t.A) * (p - t.B) * (p - t.C))
}
```

And for `Rectangle` :

```golang
type Rectangle struct {
    A, B float64
}

func (t Rectangle) Area() float64 {
    return t.A * t.B
}
```

And for `Square`:

```golang
type Square struct {
    A float64
}
func (t Square) Area() float64 {
    return t.A * t.A
}
```

Here you have `Circle`, with radius of 1.0, and other shapes with their sides:

```golang
shapes := []Shape{
    Circle{1.0},
    Square{1.772453},
    Rectangle{5, 10},
    Triangle{10, 4, 7},
}
```

Interesting! How can we collect them all in one place?
First you need `Shape interface` to collect them all in one slice of shape `[]Shape` :

```golang
type Shape interface {
    Area() float64
}
```

Now you can collect them like this:

```golang
shapes := []Shape{
    Circle{1.0},
    Square{1.772453},
    Rectangle{5, 10},
    Triangle{10, 4, 7},
}
```

After all, `Circle` is a `Shape` and `Triangle` is a `Shape` too.
Now you can print the area of each shape using the single statement `v.Area()`:

```golang
for _, v := range shapes {
    fmt.Println(v, "\tArea:", v.Area())
}
```

So `Area()` is a common interface between all shapes.
Now, how can we calculate and call uncommon method like angles of triangle using above `shapes`?

```golang
func (t Triangle) Angles() []float64 {
    return []float64{angle(t.B, t.C, t.A), angle(t.A, t.C, t.B), angle(t.A, t.B, t.C)}
}
func angle(a, b, c float64) float64 {
    return math.Acos((a*a+b*b-c*c)/(2*a*b)) * 180.0 / math.Pi
}
```

Now it's time to extract `Triangle` from above `shapes`:

```golang
for _, v := range shapes {
    fmt.Println(v, "\tArea:", v.Area())
    if t, ok := v.(Triangle); ok {
        fmt.Println("Angles:", t.Angles())
    }
}
```

Using `t, ok := v.(Triangle)` we requested type assertions, meaning we asked the compiler to try to convert `v` of type `Shape` to type `Triangle`, so that if it's successful, the `ok` will be `true` otherwise `false`, and then if it is successful call `t.Angles()` to calculate the triangle's three angles.

This is the output:

```golang
Circle (Radius: 1)  Area: 3.141592653589793
Square (Sides: 1.772453)    Area: 3.1415896372090004
Rectangle (Sides: 5, 10)    Area: 50
Triangle (Sides: 10, 4, 7)  Area: 10.928746497197197
Angles: [128.68218745348943 18.194872338766785 33.12294020774379]
```

And the whole working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "math"

func main() {
    shapes := []Shape{
        Circle{1.0},
        Square{1.772453},
        Rectangle{5, 10},
        Triangle{10, 4, 7},
    }
    for _, v := range shapes {
        fmt.Println(v, "\tArea:", v.Area())
        if t, ok := v.(Triangle); ok {
            fmt.Println("Angles:", t.Angles())
        }
    }
}

type Shape interface {
    Area() float64
}
type Circle struct {
    Radius float64
}
type Triangle struct {
    A, B, C float64 // lengths of the sides of a triangle.
}
type Rectangle struct {
    A, B float64
}
type Square struct {
    A float64
}

func (t Circle) Area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * t.Radius * t.Radius
}

// Heron's Formula for the area of a triangle
func (t Triangle) Area() float64 {
    p := (t.A + t.B + t.C) / 2.0 // perimeter half
    return math.Sqrt(p * (p - t.A) * (p - t.B) * (p - t.C))
}
func (t Rectangle) Area() float64 {
    return t.A * t.B
}

func (t Square) Area() float64 {
    return t.A * t.A
}

func (t Circle) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint("Circle (Radius: ", t.Radius, ")")
}
func (t Triangle) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint("Triangle (Sides: ", t.A, ", ", t.B, ", ", t.C, ")")
}
func (t Rectangle) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint("Rectangle (Sides: ", t.A, ", ", t.B, ")")
}
func (t Square) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint("Square (Sides: ", t.A, ")")
}

func (t Triangle) Angles() []float64 {
    return []float64{angle(t.B, t.C, t.A), angle(t.A, t.C, t.B), angle(t.A, t.B, t.C)}
}
func angle(a, b, c float64) float64 {
    return math.Acos((a*a+b*b-c*c)/(2*a*b)) * 180.0 / math.Pi
}
```

Also see:

[Type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
> expression
>
> ```golang
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> **asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T. The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.**
>
> More precisely, if T is not an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the
> dynamic type of x is identical to the type T. In this case, T must
> implement the (interface) type of x; otherwise the type assertion is
> invalid since it is not possible for x to store a value of type T. If
> T is an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x
> implements the interface T.
>
> If the type assertion holds, the value of the expression is the value
> stored in x and its type is T. **If the type assertion is false, a
> run-time panic occurs.** In other words, even though the dynamic type of
> x is known only at run time, the type of x.(T) is known to be T in a
> correct program.
>
> ```golang
> var x interface{} = 7  // x has dynamic type int and value 7
> i := x.(int)           // i has type int and value 7
>
> type I interface { m() }
> var y I
> s := y.(string)        // illegal: string does not implement I (missing method m)
> r := y.(io.Reader)     // r has type io.Reader and y must implement both I and io.Reader
> ```
>
> A type assertion used in an assignment or initialization of the
> special form
>
> ```golang
> v, ok = x.(T)
> v, ok := x.(T)
> var v, ok = x.(T)
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of ok is true if
> the assertion holds. Otherwise it is false and the value of v is the
> zero value for type T. **No run-time panic occurs in this case**.

---

## EDIT

*Question*: What does the assertion `x.(T)` return when T is an `interface{}` and not a concrete type?
*Answer*:

> It asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.

E.g. this panics (compile: Success, Run: `panic: interface conversion: interface is nil, not interface {}`):

```golang
package main

func main() {
    var i interface{} // nil
    var _ = i.(interface{})
}
```

And this works (Run: OK):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i interface{} // nil
    b, ok := i.(interface{})
    fmt.Println(b, ok) // <nil> false

    i = 2
    c, ok := i.(interface{})
    fmt.Println(c, ok) // 2 true

    //var j int = c // cannot use c (type interface {}) as type int in assignment: need type assertion
    //fmt.Println(j)
}
```

Output:

```golang
<nil> false
2 true
```

**NOTE:** here `c` is of type `interface {}` and not `int`.

See this working sample code with commented outputs:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    const fm = "'%T'\t'%#[1]v'\t'%[1]v'\t%v\n"
    var i interface{}
    b, ok := i.(interface{})
    fmt.Printf(fm, b, ok) // '<nil>'    '<nil>' '<nil>' false

    i = 2
    b, ok = i.(interface{})
    fmt.Printf(fm, b, ok) // 'int'  '2' '2' true

    i = "Hi"
    b, ok = i.(interface{})
    fmt.Printf(fm, b, ok) // 'string'   '"Hi"'  'Hi'    true

    i = new(interface{})
    b, ok = i.(interface{})
    fmt.Printf(fm, b, ok) // '*interface {}'    '(*interface {})(0xc042004330)' '0xc042004330'  true

    i = struct{}{}
    b, ok = i.(interface{})
    fmt.Printf(fm, b, ok) // 'struct {}'    'struct {}{}'   '{}'    true

    i = fmt.Println
    b, ok = i.(interface{})
    fmt.Printf(fm, b, ok) // 'func(...interface {}) (int, error)'   '(func(...interface {}) (int, error))(0x456740)'    '0x456740'  true

    i = Shape.Area
    b, ok = i.(interface{})
    fmt.Printf(fm, b, ok) // 'func(main.Shape) float64' '(func(main.Shape) float64)(0x401910)'  '0x401910'  true
}

type Shape interface {
    Area() float64
}
```

Comment: Great explanation! I understand it much better now. Just one more thing, if I may ask you to complement: what does the assertion return when T is an interface and not a concrete type?

Comment: @user1283776 : `var _ = i.(interface{})` if `i` is nil it panics.  but in `b, ok := i.(interface{})` if `i` is nil then `ok` is false, otherwise `ok` is true and `b` is of type `interface{}`, and see end of this post for sample codes.

Comment: Fantastic answer that really demystifies the concept. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A type assertion is the x.(T) notation where x is of interface type and T is a type. Additionally, the actual value stored in x is of type T, and T must satisfy the interface type of x.

Comment: Good point: a type assertion can be used to check whether the given type fully implements the given interface.  To do this at compile time, you can put the assertion in `init()` and assign it to `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Common usecase: check if returned error is of a type T.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

For a single return value assertion: when it fails the program panics.

For a two return values assertion: when it fails second argument is set to false and the program doesn't panic.