# Is a Go interface value an entire variable that implements the interface?

Tags: go, interface

New to Go here. I was taking a [tour](https://tour.golang.org) of Go and came across one word that I was confused what it was.

It's the 11th page of the *Method* section [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/11). It says, "*interface values can be thought of as a tuple of a value and a concrete type*."

My understanding is that an *interface value* is a variable that implements that interface. E.g.:

```
type Animal interface {
    run()
}

type Cat struct { … }

func main() {
    kitty := Cat{ … }
}

func (c Cat) run() { … }
```

Is `kitty` an interface value?

Comment: No kitty is not an interface value. `kitty` is a value of type `Cat`. Although type `Cat` implements the `Animal` interface, `kitty`'s type is the concrete type `Cat`.

Comment: Since you uttered that you're new to Go. Maybe you can have a look at the concept _composition over inheritence_ which interfaces of Go is based on.

Comment: Composition over inheritance has nothing to do with interfaces. While you can compose interfaces, that is a feature of interfaces, not the basis of interfaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case since you used [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) to create `kitty`, the type is inferred from the right-hand side expression, and type of `kitty` will be the concrete type `Cat`.

But since the `Cat` *concrete* type (non-interface type) implements the `Animal` [*interface*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) type, you may assign a value of `Cat` to a variable whose type is `Animal`, like in this example:

```
kitty := Cat{}
var kitty2 Animal = kitty
```

*"Implements"* by spec means:

> An interface type specifies a [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) called its *interface*. A variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method set that is any superset of the interface. Such a type is said to *implement the interface*.

Interface values, schemantically, contain a (value; type) pair, being the value stored in them, and their concrete type.

For more details about interface internals, read blog post: [The Go Blog: The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)
And [Go Data Structures: Interfaces (by Russ Cox)](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces).

For an introduction why interfaces are needed or how / when to use them, see [Why are interfaces needed in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092925/why-are-interfaces-needed-in-golang/39100038#39100038)

Answer (score 1):

"interface values can be thought of as a tuple of a value and a concrete type." -> The interface in a way just cares if your type implements the methods it needs. It's data structure stores two things : 1. The type which implements it 2. A value (of the type in #1)

Here's a simple example just to give you an idea what it is like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Animal interface {
    run()
}

type Cat struct {
    a int
}

func main() {
    kitty := Cat{2}
    var anim Animal
    fmt.Println(kitty)
    kitty.run()
    anim = kitty //interface
    fmt.Println(anim)
    anim.run()
    t := reflect.TypeOf(anim)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(anim)
    fmt.Println(t.String())
    fmt.Println(v)

}

func (c Cat) run() {
    fmt.Println("Have fun")
}
```

Output :

```
{2}
Have fun
{2}
Have fun
main.Cat
{2}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/xeozR3VT-9J though you'd need to read up more and try a few examples on your own to understand this better.