# Avoid duplicate functions which using same values from diffrent struct type

Tags: go

I’ve a method which should get the different types , how it’s suggested to solve this instead duplicate functions that doing basically the same… (I want to avoid creating wrapper struct....)

```
type A1 struct {
    Spec              A1Spec    `json:"spec,omitempty"`
    Status            A1Status `json:"status,omitempty"`
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
}

type B1 struct {
    Spec               B1Spec   `json:"spec,omitempty"`
    Status            B1Status `json:"status,omitempty"`
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
}

func ExecuteA1(ctx context.Context, a1 A1, Client client.Client) error {

if a1.Spec.Type == "test" {….


}}


func ExecuteB1(ctx context.Context, b1 B1, Client client.Client) error {

if  b1.Spec.Type == "test" {….

}
….}
```

Both functions are doing the same but get different type, I want to avoid creating two functions, how its suggested to solve this?

https://play.golang.org/p/kV7s3LRd-eh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using interfaces. Have both `A1` and `B1` implement an interface which has a method to acquire (return) the type. Then you only need a single `Execute()` function which expects a value of this interface type, can call the method defined by the interface. And then you can pass either a value of `A1` or `B1`, or any other type that implements the interface.

For example:

```
type HasType interface {
    GetType() string
}

func (a A1) GetType() string {
    return a.Spec.Type
 }

func (b B1) GetType() string {
    return b.Spec.Type
}

func Execute(ctx context.Context, foo HasType, Client client.Client) error {
    if foo.GetType() == "test" {
    }
}
```

You may call it like:

```
var a A1 = ...
var b B1 = ...

Execute(ctx, a, client)
Execute(ctx, b, client)
```

See [Why are interfaces needed in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092925/why-are-interfaces-needed-in-golang/39100038#39100038)

Also note that in this specific example you could just pass the type instead of `A1` and `B1`, so the interface and method declarations could be left out.

E.g. you could create `Execute()` like this:

```
func Execute(ctx context.Context, typ string, Client client.Client) error {
    if typ == "test" {
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var a A1 = ...
var b B1 = ...

Execute(ctx, a.Spec.Type, client)
Execute(ctx, b.Spec.Type, client)
```

Comment: The method declaration must be in the same package where `B1` is declared.

Comment: could you please provide example about the second option?