# Conditionnal repositories in Golang

Tags: go, repository, repository-pattern

I'm currently running a Go API, where I have repositories allowing me to get datas from a MySQL database.

But I would like to implemant the same repositories to fetch the same data but from a MongoDB database, which's currently difficult for me.

Here's my code:

```golang
// My vehicle repository file

// Repository handling Vehicle
type VehicleRepository struct {
    conn  *sqlx.DB
}

func (r *VehicleRepository) GetVehicles(ctx context.Context, brand string) (vehicle.Vehicle, error) {
    var vehicles []*vehicle.Vehicle
    param := map[string]interface{}{"brand": brand}

    query := "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE brand = :brand"

    rows, err := r.conn.NamedQueryContext(ctx, query, param)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "query execution")
    }

    return vehicles, nil
}

// and in another file I create a repository object with all my repository (here only "Vehicle" but in reality I have plenty)
type Repositories struct {
    Vehicle    *VehicleRepository
}

func CreateRepositories(conn c.Connections) *Repositories {
    return &Repositories{
        Vehicles:      &VehicleRepository{conn, l},
    }
}
```

This code works well, but it only handle each case at a time (either in MySQL mode or in MongoDB mode), but I need to handle both MySQL and MongoDB now, and use the MongoDB repository depending of my API configuration that can be changed on fly.

I tried multiple things:

#### 1) Implementing different repositories

I tried to rename my `vehicle.go` repository `vehicle.mysql.go` and create a `vehicle.mongodb.go` implementing the mongodb repository. I renamed the `VehicleRepository` struct to `VehicleMySQLRepository` and create a `VehicleMongoDBRepository` into `vehicle.mongodb.go`, but when I try to link it to my `Repositories` in my `CreateRepositories` it breaks:

```golang
type Repositories struct {
    // Here I have `VehicleRepository` but it didn't exist anymore, and I can't set Vehicle to `VehicleMySQLRepository | VehicleMongoDBRepository`
    Vehicle    *VehicleRepository
}

func CreateRepositories(conn c.Connections, condition bool) *Repositories {
    if condition == true {
        return &Repositories{
            // Here I could do this:
            // Vehicles: &VehicleMySQLRepository{conn.Mysql, l},
            // Vehicles: &VehicleMongoDBRepository{conn.Mongo, l},
            // but it won't work because `Vehicles` will be declared multiple time, and I can't
            // have multiple `Vehicles` like `VehiclesMongo` & `VehiclesMysql`, etc...
            // because it will break all my calls on `Vehicles` in +50 files, and in reality
            // I've got over 30 repositories, if I need to duplicate each ones of them it won't do...

            Vehicles: &VehicleRepository{conn.Mongo, l},
        }
    }
    return &Repositories{
        Vehicles:     &VehicleRepository{conn.Mysql, l},
    }
}
```

---

#### 2) Conditional compiling

I came across this thinking I could create both `vehicle.mysql.go` and `vehicle.mongodb.go`, implementing their respective repository and only compile it with a `go build -tags mongo` and co, It works but I need to handle both repository at the same time, on my frontend users can chose if they use the MySQL or MongoDB database, so I can't really recompile my backend with the good implementation each time on fly.

---

#### 3) Keeping the same repositories

I also tried to don't change the repository, and handle MySQL and MongoDB connection in the fucntion itself, like in `GetVehicles()` method the `query` string is set conditionnally to the MySQL query or MongoDB query, it works but the implementation is quite gross, I would really like to make the option 1) working.

---

I don't know if my problem is clear enough, feel free to request more informations if needed in comments.

Comment: You can implement this with interfaces. Hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092925/why-are-interfaces-needed-in-golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VehicleMySQLRepository and VehicleMongoDBRepository are different structures. Therefore, in your code, it is not possible to have a member of Repository with both types as members.

Use interfaces instead of structs as members of Repository. Here's an example created using your code as a reference.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
)

type Vehicle struct {
}

type VehicleRepository interface {
    GetVehicles(ctx context.Context, brand string) ([]Vehicle, error)
}

type VehicleMySQLRepository struct {
}

func (r *VehicleMySQLRepository) GetVehicles(ctx context.Context, brand string) ([]Vehicle, error) {
    var vehicles []Vehicle
    //...
    return vehicles, nil
}

type VehicleMongoRepository struct {
}

func (r *VehicleMongoRepository) GetVehicles(ctx context.Context, brand string) ([]Vehicle, error) {
    var vehicles []Vehicle
    //...
    return vehicles, nil
}

type Repositories struct {
    Vehicle VehicleRepository
}

type Connections struct {
}

func CreateRepositories(conn Connections, condition bool) *Repositories {
    if condition == true {
        return &Repositories{
            Vehicle: &VehicleMySQLRepository{},
        }
    }
    return &Repositories{
        Vehicle:     &VehicleMongoRepository{},
    }
}

func main() {

}
```