# What determines the position of a character when looping through UTF-8 strings?

Tags: string, for-loop, go, unicode, utf-8

I am reading the section on `for` statements in the [Effective Go documentation](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) and came across this example:

```
for pos, char := range "日本\x80語" {
    fmt.Printf("Character %#U, at position: %d\n", char, pos)
}
```

The output is:

```
Character U+65E5 '日', at position: 0
Character U+672C '本', at position: 3
Character U+FFFD '�', at position: 6
Character U+8A9E '語', at position: 7
```

What I don't understand is why the positions are 0, 3, 6, and 7. This tells me the first and second character is 3 bytes long and the 'replacement rune' (U+FFFD) is 1 byte long, which I accept and understand. However, I thought `rune` was of `int32` type and therefore would be 4 bytes each, not three.

Why are the positions in a range different to the total amount of memory each value should be consuming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string` values in Go are stored as read only byte slices (`[]byte`), where the bytes are the UTF-8 encoded bytes of the (`rune`s of the) `string`. [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable-length encoding, different Unicode code points may be encoded using different number of bytes. For example values in the range `0..127` are encoded as a single byte (whose value is the unicode codepoint itself), but values greater than 127 use more than 1 byte. The [`unicode/utf8`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/) package contains UTF-8 related utility functions and constants, for example `utf8.UTFMax` reports the maximum number of bytes a valid Unicode codepoint may "occupy" in UTF-8 encoding (which is 4).

One thing to note here: *not* all possible byte sequences are *valid* UTF-8 sequences. A `string` may be *any* byte sequence, even those that are invalid UTF-8 sequences. For example the `string` value `"\xff"` represents an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence, for details, see [How do I represent an Optional String in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731687/how-do-i-represent-an-optional-string-in-go/30741287#30741287)

The [`for range`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) construct –when applied on a `string` value– iterates over the runes of the `string`:

> For a string value, the "range" clause iterates over the Unicode code points in the string starting at byte index 0. On successive iterations, the index value will be the index of the first byte of successive UTF-8-encoded code points in the string, and the second value, of type `rune`, will be the value of the corresponding code point. **If the iteration encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, the second value will be `0xFFFD`, the Unicode replacement character, and the next iteration will advance a single byte in the string.**

The `for range` construct may produce 1 or 2 iteration values. When using 2, like in your example:

```
for pos, char := range "日本\x80語" {
    fmt.Printf("Character %#U, at position: %d\n", char, pos)
}
```

For each iteration, `pos` will be byte index of the rune / character, and `char` will be the rune of the `string`. As you can see in the quote above, if the `string` is an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence, when an invalid UTF-8 sequence is encountered, `char` will be `0xFFFD` (the Unicode replacement character), and the `for range` construct (the iteration) will advance a **singe byte only**.

**To sum it up:** The position is always the byte index of the `rune` of the current iteration (or more specifically: the byte index of the first byte of the UTF-8 encoded sequence of the `rune` of the current iteration), but if invalid UTF-8 sequence is encountered, the position (index) will only be incremented by 1 in the next iteration.

A must-read blog post if you want to know more about the topic:

[The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

Comment: That blog post was very useful and I recommend anyone with a similar query to read it. I think my confusion was thinking `range` performed some implicit conversion to a slice of runes, when actually it does not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`rune` is code point. Code point is just integer. You can even use `int64` to store it if you want to. (But Unicode only has 1,114,112 code points so `int32` should be the right choice. No wonder `rune` is alias of int32 in Golang.)

Different encoding schemes encode code points in different ways. E.g. CJK character is usually encoded to 3 bytes in UTF-8, and to 2 bytes in UTF-16.

String literal in Golang is UTF-8.