# Detecting uninitialized struct fields

Tags: go

I have a service, written in golang, that can be initialized with some options. Options are passed as a struct to a constructor function. The constructor function uses default values for option fields that weren't included. Here's an example:

```
type Service struct {
  options Options
}

type Options struct {
  BoolOption bool
  StringOption string
}

const (
  DefaultBoolOption = true
  DefaultStringOption = "bar"
)

func New(opts Options) *Service {
  if !opts.BoolOption {
    opts.BoolOption = DefaultBoolOption
  }

  if len(opts.StringOption) < 1 {
    opts.StringOption = DefaultStringOption
  }

  return &Service{options: opts,}
}

...

// elsewhere in my code
o := Options{BoolOption: false,}

// sets s.options.BoolOption to true!!!
s := New(o)
```

My problem is that for `bool` or `int` option types, I can't tell whether or not a field value was set in the Options struct. For example, was `BoolOption` set to false or just not initialized?

One possible solution would be to use strings for all of my Options fields. For instance, `BoolOption` would be `"false"` rather than `false`. I could then check the length of the string to check if it was initialized.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [How do I represent an Optional String in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731687/how-do-i-represent-an-optional-string-in-go/30741287#30741287)

Comment: If you want it to be explicitly optional (and you care about uninitialized vs default value), you probably want to use `*bool` instead of `bool`. It makes things a bit harder to deal with though, so make sure you need to.

Comment: @OliviaRuth: yeah, I think that's my only real solution. But like you said, it makes things slightly more complicated. Maybe it's not that important for me to have optional inputs.

Comment: Worth noting that if the default for the boolean is "true", you should probably invert the boolean.  For example, if the boolean is "logInput", and you want it to default to on, you should probably make the boolean option instead be "noLog" and default to false.  This follows the Go axiom of making default values useful.

Comment: You have two options in here, one is use pointer for fields, the second is encapsulate the `Options` struct and generate `Get` and `Set` methods for the fields that record/check if is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **detecting** uninitialized struct fields, as a rule certain types have **zero values**, they are otherwise **`nil`** (maps and channels need to be `make`d):

```
var i int     // i = 0
var f float64 // f = 0
var b bool    // b = false
var s string  // s = ""
var m chan int// c = nil
```

There is a [tour](https://tour.golang.org/basics/12) slide which is useful.

I think you're problem involves creating a **default boolean value of true**

---

For your sake, however, if you are passing an `Option` struct into that function, and the user did not specify the options, then **yes** they will be `false` and `""` by default.

**One solution** is to create a(nother) constructor: `func NewOptions(b bool, s string) Options`

This constructor would make the bool default `true`.

You could also try an enum to simulate a boolean; the **zero value** will be `0`. So instead of `type bool` for the `Options` struct value `BoolOption`, you could use `int`:

```
const (
        TRUE
        FALSE
)
```

You could also have a `UNINITIALIZED` as zero, but I think you just want to switch the default value, rather than detecting that it is uninitialized.

So when checking a value of `Options`, you could write:

```
if opt.BoolOption == FALSE {
    // Do something with the option
} else {
    // The default option
}
```

---

A bit simpler would be to make the `BoolOption` into `notBoolOption`, and have the default be false.

---

Or, as Olivia Ruth points out, if you have the field as a pointer to a boolean, it will be remain `nil` until "initialized".

Comment: Thanks for this. I think the only other option, as @Olivia Ruth points out, I could use a pointer inside by options struct and check for nil.

Answer (score 1):

The default value for a bool is false. If you notice that you are overwriting the options value to true every time you run the code.

The default values of a strings variable is "". So if check the string with `len(opts.StringOption) == 0` or `opts.StringOption == ""` that would work as well.

https://play.golang.org/p/jifZZvoBVZ